# An object that replaces itself with a value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to do something along the lines of:

```
foo = BlackBox()
bar1 = foo.get(5)
bar2 = foo.get('bar')

print(bar1, bar2)
>>> <object> <object>

foo.resolve()

print(bar1, bar2)
>>> 5 bar
```

Is there any way to do this or something similar?

Comment: `>>>` is misplaced I think

Comment: I don't believe there is... but if you explain the context maybe there is a useful pattern that will solve your problem. (This one is a bit dangerous).

Comment: I could be totally wrong, but isn't this what the ```__repr__()``` (or ```__str__()```) function in a class is supposed to do?

Comment: No, you cannot rebind other references to a new value, not without painful hackery. And what should happen when I use `baz = [foo.get(5), foo.get('bar')]`? Then add `spam = baz[0]`, `eggs = baz[1]`. Etc.

Comment: you could (with some crazy stuff), but why would you want to?  Maybe tell us what you want to accomplish and we can point out the "right" way to do it.

Comment: What I want is to fill in a complex data structure with values pulled from a web service.  They can all be put in the same call saving myself from making many calls.  Each value will have a string to call into the service with.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't substitute the actual references, you can simply use a method to get the desired result, and cache it if it was already obtained.

You can use a queue to keep the requests you want to send to the webservice, and do them all at once:

```
class WebServiceResponse(object):
    def __init__(self, req_manager, expression):
        self.req_manager= req_manager
        self.expression= expression
        self.evaluated= False
    def get(self):
        if not self.evaluated:
            self.req_manager.process()
        return self.value

class RequestManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue=[]
    def get_result( self, expression ):
        wsr= WebServiceResponse( self, expression ) 
        self.queue.append(wsr)
        return wsr
    def process( self ):
        expressions= [e.expression for e in self.queue]
        results= webservice.evaluate( expressions)
        for e,r in zip(self.queue, results):
            e.evaluated= True
            e.value= r
        self.queue=[]

rm= RequestManager()
my_results= map(rm.get_result, ["expr1", "expr2])
my_results= map( lambda x:x.get(), my_results)
```